# Windows Universal Accordion or ExpanderView UserControl

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml

I need to make a re-usable user control like below design. It has a gridview inside with dynamic content and multiple selection option.

[image]

Since there isn't such control to use to accomplish something like this, i don't have any idea about how to make this a reality. I am really confused between using ExpanderView or DataTemplateSelector. What do you suggest me to use for making this or anything you used before for same kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this expander control sample.

https://expanderview.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

you can modify the template of that control as you want. since you need a Gridview with multiple selection I had implemented it.

```
<ExpaControl:ExpanderControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                     Width="300"
                                     IsExpanded="True"
                                     Header="Expandable View Header!!!"
                                     Expanded="ExpanderControl_Expanded"
                                     NonExpandableHeader="This is the non-expandable header">
            <GridView SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                    </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                               Fill="Gray"/>
                </GridViewItem>
            </GridView>
        </ExpaControl:ExpanderControl>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but did you get it working? I added the shared ExpaControl and ExpaResourcs folder to my proj. and corrected the namespaces. But still getting the error "ExpanderControl doesn't exist in the namespace". Also header properties doesn't effect anything.

Comment: Check your reference of the shared project folder in xaml namespace

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot to merge the ExpanderControl.xaml dictionary. Now this is a good starting point for me.

Comment: Hope you have got soln to your answer